# Matplotlib 3d Wire Frame plot not plotting as expected

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am running simulations with 2 variables: P and Q.

Both P and Q vary from [0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8]

Each combination of P and Q produce an output which I call NB_Means. 
nb_means is produced  by running the simulator with P=0.2 and varying the Q with [.2,.4,.6,.8], after which I move on to the next P (.4) and repeat the same process.

EX: so below in nb_means: p=.2&q=.2 -> 32 and p=.2&q=.4 -> 159 ... and so on

I am attempting to plot the wire frame as so:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator, FormatStrFormatter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


x=[.2,.2,.2,.2,.4,.4,.4,.4,.6,.6,.6,.6,.8,.8,.8,.8]
y=[.2,.4,.6,.8,.2,.4,.6,.8,.2,.4,.6,.8,.2,.4,.6,.8]
nb_means = [32, 159, 216, 327, 206, 282, 295, 225, 308, 252, 226, 229, 301, 276, 262, 273]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

ax.set_title('Name Based Routing')
ax.set_xlabel('Prob of Request')
ax.set_ylabel('Prob of Publish')
ax.set_zlabel('RTT')
ax.plot_wireframe(X, Y, nb_means, rstride=10, cstride=10)
plt.show()
```

[image: matplotlib output]

However, as you see in the output above... I expected the wireplot to increase along the Q axis. But it does not.

Am I setting up my x and y incorrectly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `X`, `Y`, and `nb_means` are all the problem.  They should all be 2D arrays (your `nb_means` is currently a 1D list).  You also don't need to make `X` and `Y` using meshgrid, all you need to do is reshape them all:

```
X = np.reshape(x, (4,4))
Y = np.reshape(y, (4,4))
nb2 = np.reshape(nb_means, (4,4))
...
ax.plot_wireframe(X, Y, nb2)
```

You may also not really want that rstride=10 and cstride=10.